# Neo4j : is it possible to create a read replica with only a subset of the data?

Tags: neo4j, cluster-computing

I am currently testing a Neo4J cluster with core and read replicas. 
Is it possible with Neo4J to setup a read replica to replicate only part of the data ?

What I am trying to do is to have the core servers with a complete set of data, and read replicas without historical data (=nodes and relations with a property "endDate"). Most of the time, but not always, we only need to query the current data, and don't want to have to deal with many years of historical data.

I could develop the logic myself to have two distinct Neo4J databases, for historical and current data, but if Neo4J could save me the trouble it would be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer : no, it's not possible